# LSTM using prediction as input feature for the next time step prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I started building my own LSTM neural networks a few weeks ago and there is a problem I can't solve.

I built a single hidden layer LSTM of this shape:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 36)                14976     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 37        
=================================================================
Total params: 15,013
Trainable params: 15,013
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I try to predict in t an event (0 or 1) using 34 explanatory variables observed in t and 35 explanatory variables observed in t-1 (including the target in t-1). The problem is that in t I am not supposed to know the value of the target of t-1 in t and I would like to use the prediction made in t-1 as an input feature to make my prediction in t but I don't know how to translate this into python.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I trained my model using the true target observed in the input even if my prediction was different and for the test sample I built a for loop that predicts the target for one time step at a time and replaces the target in t-1 in the input needed for the prediction in t by the prediction made in t-1. This loop works and gives what I want but I don't see how to implement something similar for the training